# How do I count the number if files in a folder with extension .log and store the count in a variable which can be passed as an array index?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I need to store the name of a first and last file present in a folder in a variable, so I need to fetch the names of the files and store it in an array.
And then fetch the first and last index of an array based on count and store these names to another variables.
These variables need to be passed as a name to a directory.

Comment: How do you propose that the array defines the first and last file? By `name` descending, or ascending _(alphabetic)_? By `size` descending, or ascending _(smallest first)_? By `extension` descending, or ascending _(alphabetic)_, By created, last accessed, or last modified `date/time` _(oldest, or newest first)_. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60488825/edit) to clarify the requirements, and to include the code you have written, which you'd like us to assist you with.

Comment: Irrespective of the sort order based on name or size, while iterating over all the files present in a folder, the file that is processed should be in first and the one processed last should be last. This is because the files in that folder are automatically downloaded in a chronological order.

Comment: It cannot be irrespective of a sort order! There has to be an order, otherwise you're effectively asking it to choose any two files! When you open a directory in lets say, Windows Explorer, the order can be anything, it's user definable. In cmd.exe, the order is usually dependent upon the file system used for the volume on which the files reside. Additionally, there's a big issue, were those files to use numeric characters, because cmd.exe generally returns, for instance, `100` before `22` and that in turn before `3`, when using an alphabetical/chronological order, despite `3` being smallest.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Compo , the files in the folder are present in the order, gspbcs_141.log to gspbcs_169.log, and hence the command I am using to download these files, necessarily downloads in that order. The folder to which these files should be archived will be named ::Datestamp::_141_169

Comment: No they aren't, the files just exist in the file system, they don't really have a specific order. However given the provided information, if they are all named the same with always the same number of digits in their basename suffix, then you should use `DIR` command, with the `/B` and `/O:N` or `O:-N` option within a [tag:for-loop] to specifically list them in the order you require. The answer provided has now been edited to show that in use.

Comment: The files present ARE downloaded in a specific order. I mean the first file that will be processed and downloaded will be gspbcs_141.log, the second will be gspbcs_142.log... and so on till gspbcs_920.log. Hence, the firstfilename should store variable 141 and lastfilename should store 920. Is that clear now? They just don't exist in the file system like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not using an array, its a simple way of getting just the first and last file names.

This will look for all files of type `.log` in `C:\temp\` and if it finds one, it will attempt to store it in the variable `%first%` provided it does not already have one stored in it.
For every matching file that it finds, it will store its name in the variable `%last%`, overwriting the previous value in that variable, meaning that when it finishes listing all files you will be left with only the last file name in `%last%`.

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "folderpath=C:\temp\"
set "filetype=.txt"

:: Sort order:  N=Name-Alphabetic, E=Extention-Alphabetic, S=Size (smallest to largest), D=Date Time (Old to new)
set "sortOrder=D"


for /f %%a in ('dir /O:%sortOrder% /b "%folderpath%*%filetype%"') do (
    if not defined first set "first=%%a"
    set /a count+=1
    set "last=%%a"
)

echo First File:%first%
echo Last File:%last%
echo Count:!count!

endlocal
```

If you want to list all files in the folder rather than just 1 type, then you can change `set "filetype=.log"` to `set "filetype="`

This will also only search the nominated folder.
To also include all sub-directories change `dir /b` to instead be `dir /s /b`

**EDIT:** 
Modified code to include sort order option and a count

Comment: This code is resulting in an error, File not found, and printing all the 3 variables blank

Comment: The exact error is The system cannot find the path specified. I have set the variable like set folderpath="C:\Oracle\EPM Automate\bin\Test" and also tried set "folderpath=C:\Oracle\EPM Automate\bin\Test". None of them is working.

Comment: Ensure you have a trailing backslash on the end of the path....so instead of `set "folderpath=C:\Oracle\EPM Automate\bin\Test"` it should be `set "folderpath=C:\Oracle\EPM Automate\bin\Test\"`

Comment: I am not using folderpath variable at all because that is resulting in an error "Cannot find the path specified" instead I added a line at the beginning "cd C:\Oracle\EPM Automate\bin\Test" This resolves the error but again, giving incorrect ouput

Comment: The above mentioned correction in the variable path name also works, but when the starting is gspbcs_141.log and last one is gspbcs_920.log, then firstname variable is printing gspbcs_1002.log. I am not sure from where this file name is been fetched.

Comment: Inside the `for` loop, add `echo %%a` to print to console the file names, also add a `pause` as last line in script. This will help you see what order they are being processed in.

Comment: Also, in the example code above it is sorting via date(`D`), if you want alphabetical you need to use `N` instead